# Importing GPG key in ubuntu:bionic Docker container

Tags: 18.04, gnupg, docker, pgp

I am trying to import a GPG key on a Gitlab CI system with an ubuntu:bionic Docker image. To do this securely, I have to store the key in a so called secret variable (which then simply becomes an environment variable at runtime).

So I tried to export the key in a non-binary format like this:

```
gpg2 --armor --export-secret-keys "my name <my email>" > my-gpg-key.asc
```

my-gpg-key.asc looked like this then:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

long multi line ascii string
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Then I copied the file contents and defined a secret variable from it.
The variable is called `LAUNCHPAD_GPG_PRIVATE_KEY`

Here is what I tried:

```
apt-get -qq update --yes
apt-get -qq install --yes gnupg2 > /dev/null
export GPG_TTY=$(tty) # compensate for ioctl error
gpg2 --list-keys
gpg2 -v --import <(echo "$LAUNCHPAD_GPG_PRIVATE_KEY")
gpg2 --list-keys
```

This causes:

```
gpg: key 17B1EA9E090F697D/17B1EA9E090F697D: error sending to agent: No such file or directory
gpg: error building skey array: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to export and import the key with gpg instead of gpg2: Same result...

I also tried running

```
gpg-agent --daemon
```

and

```
gpg-agent --daemon --allow-loopback-pinentry
```

before the import... but still: Same error.

Any ideas how this can be done properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed import it without any errors by adding the batch flag.

```
gpg2 -v --batch --import <(echo "$LAUNCHPAD_GPG_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

Don't ask me why this fixes it. It took me hours to figure this out...

Comment: There was a [change](https://dev.gnupg.org/T2313) in GnuPG 2.1 that causes it to now prompt for the private key passphrase during import in order to re-encrypt keys exported from earlier versions into a new format.  `--batch` is a workaround that defers the re-encryption until the first time the key is actually used.